# Calculate scale factor on fixed map size and dynamic object positions

Tags: php, javascript, css, math, coordinates

I need some math advice... Or, at least I think i do.

I have a set of elements in my database which represents objects (like phyisical objects) with a position (x,y,z). These positions can be totally random, like object A has a position of 1532,3512,1500 and B has a position of 2421,4612,1234.

I'm trying to create a graphical map (using CSS) of the objects in 2D. So only the X and Y coords are being used. The map I want to draw on has a specific width and height. Now here's the tricky part: I want the map to scale with the size of the map. Like, when there are 2 objects where one is at coord: 1,1 and the other on coord 3,3, I want object one to be in the top left corner of the map and the other in the bottom right.

So, here's an example of my elements (objects):

```
database elements:
  - [1] => x: 1254, y: 1642
  - [2] => x: 2311, y: 2361
  - [3] => x: 1732, y: 2351
  - [4] => x: 1436, y: 3323
```

First, I take the minimum and maximum values of these elements to create a formula which lets the coords start at 0,0 and go from there.

so, let's say the minumum x-value is 1254 in this example and Y is 1642.
I go in a for loop and do the following:

```
foreach( $this->db as $item )
{
    $x = $this->value_x_max - $item['x'];
    $y = $this->value_y_max - $item['y'];
}
```

The map size is 720x480 pixels. How do I create a formula which spreads out my objects across the map. It is important that the objects don't go outside the map boundaries but also needs to be spread out. So if 2 objects have positions 1,1 and 1,2 for example, they need to be in the top left and bottom left corners.

Can anyone help me out with this?

Any help and advise appriciated!

Comment: Possibly of interest?: [http://www.highcharts.com/](http://www.highcharts.com/)

Comment: It's not a chart that I'm trying to make but a 2D map (just a box with squares inside them which represents the objects).

Comment: I would start with trying to find some minimum/maximum values for your coords, from these you can calculate a scale factor, which in return you can apply to all coords while displaying.

Comment: Yea, that's what I did (see code in first post). But I can't seem to figure out the right formula to generate the correct scale factor... 

I have the following variables available:
- minimum-x
- maximum-x
- minimum-y
- maximum-y


- mapWidth
- mapHeight

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, but be aware, it's just a realy quick and dirty raw sketch of what came to my mind. But maybe it's enough to give you a jump start:

```
<?php
$elements = array(
    array('x' => 1254, 'y' => 1642),
    array('x' => 2311, 'y' => 2361),
    array('x' => 1732, 'y' => 2351),
    array('x' => 1436, 'y' => 3323),
);

$mapWidth = 720;
$mapHeight = 480;
$blockWidth = 10;
$blockHeight = 10;

$minimumX = $minimumY = $maximumX = $maximumY = null;
foreach ($elements as $element) {
    if ($minimumX === null || $element['x'] < $minimumX) {
        $minimumX = $element['x'];
    }
    if ($minimumY === null || $element['y'] < $minimumY) {
        $minimumY = $element['y'];
    }
    if ($maximumX === null || $element['x'] > $maximumX) {
        $maximumX = $element['x'];
    }
    if ($maximumY === null || $element['y'] > $maximumY) {
        $maximumY = $element['y'];
    }
}

foreach ($elements as $i => $element) {
    $elements[$i]['x'] -= $minimumX;
    $elements[$i]['y'] -= $minimumY;
}

$fx = ($mapWidth - $blockWidth) / ($maximumX - $minimumX);
$fy = ($mapHeight - $blockHeight) / ($maximumY - $minimumY);
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>2D</title>
        <style type="text/css">
            body {
                background: black;
            }

            #map {
                position: relative;

                margin: 20px auto;

                width: <?php echo $mapWidth; ?>px;
                height: <?php echo $mapHeight; ?>px;

                background: grey;
            }

            .dot {
                position: absolute;

                width: <?php echo $blockWidth; ?>px;
                height: <?php echo $blockHeight; ?>px;

                background: lightblue;
            }
        </style>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="map">
            <?php
                foreach ($elements as $element) {
                    printf(
                        '<div class="dot" style="left: %.1fpx; top: %.1fpx;"></div>',
                        $element['x'] * $fx,
                        $element['y'] * $fy
                    );
                }
            ?>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to work either =[ The objects are drawn in the bottom right corner and don't spread out.

Comment: That's intended, if you add an element with very small coords, it would be drawn nearer to the top left corner. Or do you want to always position the minimum values to the top/left, and the maximum values to the bottom/right?

Comment: Yes, they always should spread out to the corners of the map ;)